# Generic Method in C++

Tags: c#, c++, generic-method

I would like to create a method that will do the same actions for some types of argument.

For example: I have a file and would like the method `WriteToFile()` to write string or a int or a double to the document.

```
WriteToFile( type content)
{
streamFile.open ("path\to\file.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out| fstream::app);
streamFile<<content;
}
```

In C# I use the T, is it possible to implement it using C++?

Comment: Yes, it's called a template.

Comment: check out the C++ `template` mechanism.

Comment: you can use a template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_(C%2B%2B)) in C++ which allow you to do same logic for a different types:

```
template < typename T>
void WriteToFile( T content, File& streamFile)
{
    streamFile.open ( "path\to\file.txt", fstream::in
                                | fstream::out| fstream::app);
    streamFile << content;
}
```

That is you can create a family of functions.

Comment: Thanks, Where should I define this class? What is its content?

Comment: in the example WriteToFile is a method and should be declared in header and implemented in cpp file

Comment: What is it ? an internal class?

Comment: T is template parameter, a variable that represents many possible variables, read about the [templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_(C%2B%2B)) in C++

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and it works fine. One more thing: why should I locate the template line at the line above the method? Can I move it to another place?

Comment: no, this is to inform compiler that this what appears to be under this line is a template

Comment: It is better to use template <typename T> because T does not necessarily have to be a class. This is just meant as positive criticism, the answer is correct.

Comment: yeah, however let me notice that there is absolutely no technical difference between these two, both 'class' & 'typename' can be used with very same types

Comment: Correct I was not suggesting otherwise. But the point really is that the keyword typename is better documenting the intent of the code.